# How do I work out the degrees to rotate a wheel based on drag distance?

Tags: javascript, animation, css

I'm trying to create a animated wheel that the user can drag to rotate using CSS3 transforms and Javascript.

How do you work out how many degrees to rotate the wheel from a given drag distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the diameter of the wheel, then the angle in degrees will be

```
(360 * distance pulled)/(diameter * pi)
```

Where `distance pulled` and `diameter` will be measured in pixels.

Good luck

Comment: It doesn't matter what units the distance and diameter are measured in as long as they are they *same* unit.